# Migrate Git Repository to tfs Git while keeping all historical commits

Tags: node.js, git, tfs, migration

I need to migrate a git repository to tfs git. 
This is my first time to migrate and it is important to keep the historical data intact. any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to push all tags from the remote, they won't transfer from local clone, unless you've pulled them explicitly and then pushed them explicitly. That's what --mirror helps with.

```
 git clone --mirror source
 git push --mirror target
```

does magic. [Full documentation can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/move-git-repos-between-team-projects). Adding a remote to a local repo and pushing will push the current branch and it's history, but it may not push all objects in the current master repository and it will not push all tags and labels over if they weren't present in your local clone.

Import repository helps because it saves doing it locally and can pull directly from the source, this can be much faster than creating a local repo and then pushing it along. [It's supported in VSTS, TFS 2017u1+ and TFS2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository.). But it does require a direct line of sight between both servers and may require you to setup alternate credentials or a Personal Access Token.

Local clone method:

```
 LOCAL <- SOURCE
 LOCAL -> TARGET
```

Import repository option:

```
 TARGET <- SOURCE
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TFS do you use? If you are using TFS 2017 Update1 or later version, then you can [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository) in TFS directly.

For earlier version, you can follow jessehouwing or Mark's answer. And personally I think `git clone --mirror source` it's much better.

You can also reference this thread : https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/8972566

Comment: Yes, I followed jessehouwing solution and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Migrating to a tfs git repository is the same as migrating to any other git repository.  In the following, you need (a clone of) the source repo locally, and the git repo in tfs will become the remote.

So first you find a URL for the remote.  You can get this from the TFS web UI; it should give it to you in the instruction page you get when first creating the repo, or if the repo already exists in tfs, you can click the "clone" button to get the URL.

Then you add this as a remote to the local repo.

```
git remote add tfs url/of/remote
```

Then you push your refs to the remote; git will send complete histories automatically.

```
git push --all tfs
```

Comment: It would be better to perform a `git pull --mirror` to a new location. Or use the TFS import repository functionality if your TFS version already supports that

Comment: I get fatal: authentication failed for URL. and yes, TFS import was my first thing to try I got 
You do not have permission to create a service endpoint. A Project Collection Administrator should add you to the Endpoint Creators group.

Comment: @jessehouwing - In what way would those be "better"?  (Spoiler alert: they aren't. The first isn't even applicable as you can't "pull" into TFS. The second is no better than pushing refs; it's just a convenience for people who are familiar with MS tooling but not with git.)

Comment: @Mindan - Based on both errors, it sounds like you don't have necessary TFS permissions. If you maintain the TFS instance, then it's a TFS question and you should start by consulting the appropriate documentation.  If someone else maintains the TFS instance, you should follow up with them.